# Display both jQuery validation summary and individual error messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation in ASP.net MVC. I would like to show validation summary and also individual error messages besides the control. I can do either one at a time. So it would be really helpful to know how can I display both.

Comment: Please show some sample code as to what you have tried so far, what's the expected result and what's the actual result. Remember that the more details you give the more precise answer you will probably get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for JQuery only solution. I have no idea about the ASP .net MVC part.

You could use these hooks to accomplish most of it you want.

```
invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
// show the summary info here
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
// element level error display manipulation
},
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
// Callback when the errors are actually shown
}
```

Check some of the examples in the jQuery validation plugin [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator).