# Display both summary and individual error messages using the jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

How can I display both individual error messages and summary for the jQuery plugin?

I actually found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520119/display-both-jquery-validation-summary-and-individual-error-messages) , but it just references some hooks I can use, but I'm not sure where to start.

I got the displaying individual error messages part, but I need to display the summary in an alert box on submit, and plugin can be found [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Just found out how, thanks for David's code, and on my follow-up question - The alert box would be "First Name: Please enter a valid First Name".

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var submitted = false;
    ('.selector').validate({
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if (submitted) {
                var summary = "You have the following errors: \n";
                $.each(errorMap, function(key, value) {
               summary += key + ': ' + value + "\n";
                });
                alert(summary);
                submitted = false;
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            submitted = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the linked question says, the `showErrors` callback is called whenever errors are shown.  You can use this to create your summary and alert it.  You can then call `this.defaultShowErrors()` to display the normal individual error messages.

By default showErrors is called for a lot of events (submit, keyup, blur, etc).  You could either disable those, or use the `invalidHandler` method which is only called when an invalid form is submitted.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var submitted = false;
    ('.selector').validate({
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if (submitted) {
                var summary = "You have the following errors: \n";
                $.each(errorList, function() { summary += " * " + this.message + "\n"; });
                alert(summary);
                submitted = false;
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },          
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            submitted = true;
        }
    });
});
```

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) for a complete list of options that can be passed to the `validate` method.

Comment: Wow thanks is there anyway I can have it display which element is having the error, 

for example the First Name field is having the error,

the alert box would be "First Name: Please enter a valid First Name".

And is it possible to have an alternate error message in the alert box?

I mean if the default error is "This enter a valid First Name", in the alertbox it would say "Please include atleast 1 character"