# Jquery Validation general errors?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I want to be able to check the validity of the form. If there are any errors I want to display a general error div with instructions to review the form. Can anyone help me out with the syntax?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information than this. What have you tried so far? Is there any framework you want to use or want to avoid? Have you looked up the
[jQuery Validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) yet?

Comment: Good point Zero, I apologize for being so vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){ //when form is submitted
        var errors = false; //errors start as false
        if($('.email').val() === ''){ //this is where you can validate fields
            errors = true; //if validation fails errors = true
        }
        if(errors){ //if it does not pass validation
            event.preventDefault(); //don't submit form
            $('errorDiv').show(); //show the hidden div that tells the user there are errors
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty good place to start:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var submitted = false;
    ('.selector').validate({
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if (submitted) {
                var summary = "You have the following errors: \n";
                $.each(errorList, function() { summary += " * " + this.message + "\n"; });
                alert(summary);
                submitted = false;
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },          
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            submitted = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Courtest of David Fullterton: [Display both summary and individual error messages using the jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848765/display-both-summary-and-individual-error-messages-using-jquery-validation-plugi)