# appending to showError function in jquery validation and jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using a third party tool that uses

- jquery.validate.min.js
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

when i enter the following which shows a messagebox. The custom validation on  the tool validatiion fails. I would assume it also uses "showError". I appreciate this is hard question to ask with out the full code base. My question is...

Is there an event that occurs after `showErrors`. Or is there a way to extend to this function as opposed to overriding it.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
   showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $(".messagebox").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to preserve the default error display and add your own? If so, just add                 `this.defaultShowErrors();` to your custom handler.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
   showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $(".messagebox").show();
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

See: [Display both summary and individual error messages using the jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848765/display-both-summary-and-individual-error-messages-using-jquery-validation-plugi).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an event that occurs after `showErrors`.

See documentation for all callback functions:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

> Or is there a way to extend to this function as opposed to overriding
>   it.

No. Using your custom callback function (over-ride) is the typical way to do this.

Looking [inside the plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js); it checks to see if you have a custom callback function declared and then uses yours instead of the default...

```
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors
    showErrors: function( errors ) {
        if ( errors ) {
            // add items to error list and map
            $.extend( this.errorMap, errors );
            this.errorList = [];
            for ( var name in errors ) {
                this.errorList.push({
                    message: errors[name],
                    element: this.findByName(name)[0]
                });
            }
            // remove items from success list
            this.successList = $.grep( this.successList, function( element ) {
                return !(element.name in errors);
            });
        }
        if ( this.settings.showErrors ) {
            this.settings.showErrors.call( this, this.errorMap, this.errorList );
        } else {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        }
    }


    defaultShowErrors: function() {
        var i, elements;
        for ( i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++ ) {
            var error = this.errorList[i];
            if ( this.settings.highlight ) {
                this.settings.highlight.call( this, error.element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
            }
            this.showLabel( error.element, error.message );
        }
        if ( this.errorList.length ) {
            this.toShow = this.toShow.add( this.containers );
        }
        if ( this.settings.success ) {
            for ( i = 0; this.successList[i]; i++ ) {
                this.showLabel( this.successList[i] );
            }
        }
        if ( this.settings.unhighlight ) {
            for ( i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
            }
        }
        this.toHide = this.toHide.not( this.toShow );
        this.hideErrors();
        this.addWrapper( this.toShow ).show();
    }
```