# jquery validation - how to set a general error message

Tags: validation, jquery-plugins

The documentation for jquery.validation here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/ states that it is possible to set a general message (q.v. General messages) for which you can set the container via the errorContainer option.

However... it doesn't tell one how to actually set, nor trigger, that general error message. How does one do that?

Comment: If you refer validation js, you will find , error messages were set and you can include your error messages  or custome validation

Comment: That does not answer the question. Please read it carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this on another stackoverflow question:

[Display both summary and individual error messages using the jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848765/display-both-summary-and-individual-error-messages-using-jquery-validation-plugi)